# Make a babel 7 config take effect in a sibling directory

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am working on a project consisting of three parts: a Client, a Server and a Common directory which contains things I want to import from both the Client and the Server. Everything can use both JS and TS. (Thanks to the `babel-typescript` preset)

### Directory structure

Here is how it looks like:

```
root/
├── babel.config.js
├── Common/
│   ├── helper1.ts
│   ├── helper2.ts
│   ├── helper3.js
├── Client/
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── file1.js
│   └── .babelrc.js
└── Server/
    ├── src/
    │   └── file1.js
    └── .babelrc.js
```

### Babel config files

Here is what my `root/babel.config.js` looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
    plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-for-of", { assumeArray: true }],
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", { proposal: "minimal" }],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind",
    ],
};
```

And here is what my `Server/.babelrc.js` looks like:

```js
const moduleAlias = require("./tools/module-alias");
const rootConfig = require("../babel.config");

module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ...rootConfig.presets,
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                targets: {
                    node: "current",
                },
                exclude: ["transform-for-of"],
            },
        ],
    ],
    plugins: [
        ...rootConfig.plugins,
        [
            "babel-plugin-module-resolver",
            {
                root: ["."],
                alias: moduleAlias.relativeAliases,
                extensions: [".js", ".ts"],
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

I will omit the `Client/.babelrc.js` since it's very similar to the Server one.

### Basic test files

Here is an example `Common/helper3.js` file:

```
function doubleSay(str) {
    return `${str}, ${str}`;
}

function capitalize(str) {
    return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}

function exclaim(str) {
    return `${str}!`;
}

const result = "hello" |> doubleSay |> capitalize |> exclaim;

console.log(result);
```

And inside `Server/src/index.js` I just import the file `Common/helper3.js`.

### The error

Then, inside the `Server` directory, I do this:

```
npx babel-node src/index.js  -x .ts,.js
```

Which prints the following error:

```
const result = "hello" |> doubleSay |> capitalize |> exclaim;
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
```

I am  definitely sure this error is related to my "strange" directory structure since it's fine when I put this exact file under `Server/src`.

### The question

**How can I keep this directory structure and tell Babel to use a config when it processes files within the `Common` directory?**

I don't use Lerna or anything. I have setup special aliases that resolve `$common` to `../Common` where needed. I know there is no issue with this since the file is properly found by Babel (otherwise I would get a "File not found" error)

#### Note

This `babel` structure is one of my attempt to fix the issue above. Originally I only had one `babel.config.js` inside `Server` and another inside `Client`. I thought having one at the root would solve this problem but it didn't change anything.

#### Edit after searching a lot more:

After taking a look at the babel code to find the config parsing, I noticed that this line : https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/8ca99b9f0938daa6a7d91df81e612a1a24b09d98/packages/babel-core/src/config/config-chain.js#L456 is called (`null` is returned).
I printed everything in this scope and noticed that babel automatically generates an `only` parameter containing the cwd. (Effectively saying that my `babel.config.js` doesn't affect my `common` directory despite being "above" is in the directory hierarchy).
I decided to try overloading it in the command line and arrived at this command:

```
npx babel-node src/index.js --root-mode upward -x .ts,.js --only .,../Common/ --ignore node_modules
```

(Added `--only` and `--ignore`)
This made me progress a bit: instead of failing to parse advanced syntax (pipeline operator) **in js files**, it failed on a ts failing, saying

```
export const accountStatus = Object.freeze({
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

What I don't understand is how it can parse the pipeline operator but not the typescript file even though both the pipeline plugin and the typescript are inside the same `babel.config.js`

### Edit after solving this last issue:

Adding `--only` and `--ignore` made it work. The other issue was because I forgot to add the `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` plugin and it was not able to resolve the import.

The slight change I did was adding `ignore: ["**/node_modules"],` to my root `babel.config.js` file and change my command to use those arguments: `--root-mode upward -x .ts,.js --ignore __fake__`.

Adding a random `--ignore` is enough to prevent `babel` from guessing by itself.

This is the solution I use and it works fine even though it's not very elegant.

Comment: If not mistaken you can specify an `enviroment` for either develop and deploy. For each environment you can specify specific plugins etc. so you don't need to keep 2 seperate config files

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924581/how-do-you-configure-babel-to-run-with-different-configurations-in-different-env

Comment: Yes, I know about that but how would it solve my issue? The issue is that `babel-node` doesn't transpile files inside my `Common` directory, even when imported from within `Server`. It acts as if there were no config specified at all.

Comment: The babelrc.js file should be on the root of the project. Also bablerc.js and babel.config are the same file/ do the same. So I guess it is better to have all of them combined into one config or babelrc file at the root

Comment: Yes but the reason I have multiple ones is because the Client and Server don't use the same plugins/presets. Using `environment` for this would feel more like a hack, I think.

Comment: This babel structure is one of my attempt to fix the issue above. Originally I only had one `babel.config.js` inside `Server` and another inside `Client`. I thought having one at the root would solve this problem but it didn't change anything.