# Docker secret nextjs env variables are not available at runtime

Tags: docker, next.js, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I am trying to set environment variables in my dockerfile that are available at runtime after running the next js app via `npm run start` (next start).

I have read that I need to use `ENV` variables in my dockerfile to have these env variables available at runtime. `ARG` variables in dockerfile are only available at build time.

So I am running the docker build command wih `--build-arg` and it is working with my `NEXT_PUBLIC...` variables but it wont work for my secret non public env variabels.

here is my content of `.env` file in nextjs:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=my-public-key...
RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=my-secret-key...
```

this is my docker run command from my Gitlab CI:

`docker build --build-arg NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY="$NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY" --build-arg RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY="$RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY" -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/nextjs:${CI_COMMIT_SHA} ./nextjs`

the docker file:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=node:14.16.0-alpine3.13

# Build
FROM $BASE_IMAGE as BUILD
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./package-lock.json ./
RUN CI=true npm ci
COPY . ./

ARG RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=recaptchasecrect_placeholder
ENV RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=${RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}

ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=recaptchasitekey_placeholder
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=${NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}

RUN npm run build

# Run
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=BUILD /app ./
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If I put `ENV RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=my-secret-key...` hardcoded into the dockerfile above `EXPOSE 3000` it will work and the .env variable is available at runtime.

Why is my `NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY` variable available at runtime and my `RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY` variable that is set the same way not?

Comment: When executing `docker build` are you sure the environment variables are set in your host environment? (I.E. did you load your `.env` file first?) in other words are you sure of the value you are passing to `--build-arg`? Try echoing the value before `docker build` and also confirm with a test echoing the buildarg value with a `RUN` command. Also when you hardcode the `ENV` are you putting it above or below the last `FROM` instruction?

Answer (score -1):

When you run the next app, the variables in .evn will only load to next app if they start with NEXT_PUBLIC_, remember you are not running the next app from cmd, your starting point is 'npm start' in docker which only loads env variable with names stating from "NEXT_PUBLIC"

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=abcdefghijk
```

More info here - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Just prefix all your variables with "NEXT_PUBLIC"

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=my-public-key...
NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=my-secret-key...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then my NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY is exposed to the client and I want to keep that var only available to the server. So this isnt an option for me, or am I missing something? All vars in my .env file not prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_...` are not exposed to the client/browser. This is what I want.

Comment: Ha got it, Can you check these links
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12077
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462890/1554860